# STOCKHISTORY has different behaviours for the same date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with these two functions in two different cells:

```
=STOCKHISTORY("ETIHX", "2024/01/10",, 0,0,1)
=STOCKHISTORY("ABBV", "2024/01/10",, 0,0,1)
```

The second returns a value (for `ABBV`), the first returns an error with "Non-trading days".

[image]

I have tried to change the format of the date (even "10 January 2024") but nothing changes, the day is ok with `ABBV` and wrong with `ETIHX`.

OLD: If I switch the symbols, the error switches place. In another Excel file I have, Excel has no problems with `ETIHX` for the same day. I had no problems with `ETIHX` for other dates I tested with.

NEW: I have just noticed that the problem occurs only with ETIHX (at least among the symbols I am tracking).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the source Excel uses for financial data is just missing data for that day, it will probably get updated within a few days.

See what happens when you try this to get a range of days:

```
=STOCKHISTORY("ETIHX", "2024/01/1","2024/01/11")
```

[image]

Excel skips the days for which it has no data (notice the weekends are missing). Since it has skipped yesterday and today, it means there is no data. Nothing wrong with the formula or the formula's behaviour, just a problem with the source data.

Comment: The problem occurs every once in a while only for the symbol ETIHX. I am tracking over 50 symbols and have no problems with 49+ of them. Only with ETIHX...

Comment: To answer your question: Excel is not able to fetch the value for ETIHX for yesterday Janyary 16, 2023. If I run your formula with 2024/01/16, Excel is indeed able to fetch the values for all the dates, including January 2024/01/16 (and keeps returning no values if I query with that single day).

Comment: I am trying the formula now with `=STOCKHISTORY("ETIHX", "2024/01/1","2024/01/17")`. It does not fetch data past 12 Jan. This simply means the source data does not have data for 12 Jan. There is no issue with the formula. The fact that it happens with only one of your stocks is not significant.

Comment: To further illustrate the point, the data for 10 January is now being returned, confirming there was just a temporary issue with the 10 January data that has now been resolved. There is no issue with the formula or the way you are using it.

Comment: I have the same error for ETIHX yesterday and today for, respectively, January 16 and 17: no close price. No problems with the others...

Comment: Perfect that again confirms the answer. Is there something else you are looking for?